# Definition Dotnet MAUI "device-independent" unit of measure

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

Can someone point me to an article explaining the definition of a "device-independent" unit of measure? I am coming up dry.

Comment: A "device (or density)-independent pixel (or unit)" (DIP or DP) is approximately 1/160 inch. This is the pixel size of the original iPhone. Later iPhones, with higher resolution, adopted that as a way to be independent of the pixel resolution. Similarly, Android's "Density" says (approximately) how many pixels are in one DIP. Xamarin Forms and Maui continue this de facto standard. Note that this is not an EXACT value; 160 DIPs will not be exactly an inch on most devices.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Xamarin Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05) (Since there is not documentation of this on dotnet maui) the "device-independent" units of measure are used as a standard for measurement of the same kind of quantity. Some values are default but You could set those in different controls (using CharacterSpacing / RowDefinition / ColumnDefinition / etc )

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of WPF, Microsoft began using DIU (Device Independent Units). A DIU (also known as a Device Independent Pixel, or DIP) measurement is based on inches rather than hardware-specific pixels. A DIU is defined as 1/96 of an inch (smaller than the point, which is defined as 1/72 of an inch).

For a standard 96 pixel per inch monitor, 96 DIU = 96 pixels. For monitors with 120 pixels/inch, 96 DIU = 120 pixels. For a monitor with 60 pixels/inch, 10 DIU = 60 pixels. When the measurement doesn't work out to a perfectly round number (as is often the case), WPF will automatically use anti-aliasing, or you have the option of “snapping” to the nearest pixel if you don't want "fuzzy" outlines for your button, etc.
For more information about WPF, you can refer to the documentation [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).